# write xth row in file in Java

Tags: java, file, io

in Java, suppose I have a text file with n rows, is it possible to only write and replace row x?  or do I rewrite all the rows in order to edit any row?

It seems that I have use RandomAccess File to read x-1 lines, and then call

```
f.writeChars(str+"\n");
```

would this work? but also it won't delete the existing xth line..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not changing the line length, you can simply overwrite the original data.

If you need to change the line length, or add (or remove) a row in the middle of the file, then you need to rewrite all the data starting from that point till the end.

Answer (score 1):

See [RandomAccessFile](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html).

It wouldn't be pretty though because if you start writing in a given position you're overwriting whatever is there, so you will probably have to save and rewrite everything after that point (that is, you can't just "insert" text in there).

**Re: your edit:**
It will delete the existing line and maybe more (or less) depending on the length of the line.